# open rtf on android - developing

Tags: android, api, rtf

I need open arabic documents on android. Arabic is very specific language, and I need open on all (no-arabic specific) android phones.

I investigate about that, and I can save my Arabic files only as RTF or MHT. But both RTF, and MHT does not supported on android.

I think MHT is windows specific format, and I can use only RTF.

**How open RTF file on android?**

Or, maybe, someone have other, better, solution?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. User questions should go to http://android.stackexchange.com or a similar forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your RTF file into HTML and next open it in Android. HTML has to be fully supported in Android even with RTL Arabic.

Comment: Hi Maximus,

Thanks for reply. I investigate few days, and i found "zwj" parameter for HTML. Perhaps this is the solution of my problem.

BR
Kolesar